# Bootstrap Carousel - Autoplay video on active slide but pause video when in active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am trying to use Bootstrap carousel with videos. I have a list of videos and images. I need to auto-play them using this carousel.

Currently, Bootstrap plays the every first video but I also wish to automatically play all other videos when the slide into the screen. But, every first video play, the other video also playing too although the screen inactive.

Or, when the carousel returns to the first screen, the video has ended. that's my problem
Any thoughts?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner" >
        <div class="carousel-item active" >
            <video id="myVideo" height="400"  autoplay muted>
                <source src="../../lib-indah/asset/content/6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <video id="myVideo" height="400"  autoplay muted>
                <source src="../../lib-indah/asset/content/6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="../../lib-indah/asset/content/1.jpg" height="300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
$('video').on('play', function (e) {
    $(".carousel").carousel('pause');
    
});
$('video').on('ended', function (e) {
    $(".carousel").carousel('cycle');
});
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
    if (currentIndex == 1) {
        $('#myVideo').play()
    }
});
```

i want to make carousel bootstrap with video lists and some images. but when video playing, the other video on inactive screen stop to play. and, when the screen active again the video also playing